# Use SSH hostname aliases in browser

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, hostname, hosts-file

I set up hostname aliases in `.ssh/config`, which works great:

```
Host my-web
  HostName 515.346.96.21
```

So I can do this:

```
ssh my-web
```

But in a browser, I still need to type in "`http://515.346.96.21`". It would be great to be able to do "`http://my-web`".

Short of using a Dynamic DNS, or writing a script to synchronise changes with `/etc/hosts`, is there a way to use the aliases in SSH more widely? I create and destroy VMs with different IPs pretty often, so am constantly updating `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: What's your error in your brwoser?

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find ..."

Comment: it's easy. put http:// before my-web , chrome doesn't understand protocol type and refer your string to search engine.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can't re-use the HostName alias from ~/.ssh/config elsewhere. What you could do is update your /etc/hosts file with entries for your hosts e.g.

```
515.346.96.21 myweb
```

Comment: Well yes - an option I referred to and dismissed, as it doubles the time spent.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Sometimes it's necessary to (re)state the obvious in the face of unreasonable expectations.

Comment: Heh. When my question says "...short of [updating] /etc/hosts", I don't think "you could...update your /etc/hosts file" is useful. But anyway. Sorry to be a jerk.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Apology accepted.

Answer (score 2):

On further reflection, this seems like the way to go:

In `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.0.27    my-server
```

In `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host my-server
IdentityFile ~/foo.pem
User ubuntu
```

You still have to edit two files, but at least you're not duplicating any information. If the IP changes, you update /etc/hosts. If key or user change, your update .ssh/config. Plus, host name wildcards still work:

`/etc/hosts`:

```
company-server1: 192.168.0.44
company-server2: 192.168.0.45
company-server3: 192.168.0.46
```

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host company-*
IdentityFile ~/foo.pem
User ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just forget about setting aliases anywhere, if you use something like [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29). This lets your workstation and servers (even virtual ones, if you bridged the virtual network) find each other and address each other by name.

Comment: Interesting to know about, but wouldn't really work. The hosts aren't on my local network, and installing something on each one would be more work than updating /etc/hosts.

Comment: In that case you're left with updating `/etc/hosts`.